401 Unauthorized Error When Accessing HBase in .NET 8
I have been successfully accessing an HBase service in my .NET 8 application without any issues until recently. Suddenly, I started receiving a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to connect to the service.
I haven't changed any code related to the authentication process, and I'm unsure what could have caused this issue. Here are some details:
.NET Version: 8
HBase Client Library: No specific library
Error Message: 401 Unauthorized / System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Authentication validation failed with error - InvalidToken.'
Environment: all environments
Authentication Method: Kerberos
    public class GetHbaseService
    {
        public async Task<object> ConnectAsync(string endpoint, string tableName, string rowId)
        {
            string url = $"{endpoint}/{tableName}/{rowId}";
            using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                // Setting up the Kerberos authentication
                handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }     
                    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


The service is up and running.
My credentials have not changed.
There have been no updates or changes to the HBase server configuration that I'm aware of.
Could someone help me understand what might have changed and how I can resolve this issue? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
What I Tried:
I attempted to connect to the HBase service using the same credentials and code that previously worked. I also verified that the HBase service is operational and that there have been no changes to my codebase or environment.
What I Expected:
I expected to successfully connect to the HBase service without encountering any authentication errors.
What Actually Resulted:
Instead of a successful connection, I received a 401 Unauthorized error. This was unexpected as I have not changed my credentials or the authentication method.
